What does とはなる here mean?

都民からの税金で[賄]{まかな}われていると言えば、結局自分たちの支払いだとはなるけど

The character is a government official that ponders who is paying them... Given they also reside in Tokyo he concludes they are paying themselves .


[sentence]となる

I'd say this is implicit quoted speech - implicit in the sense that the verb and noun that do quotation, like 言う + some noun/nominalization, is omitted. The meaning is something along the lines of "I would say __" and "That would make me say __".
If I try to fill the omitted part in the quotation, it would be something like:

結局自分たちの支払いだと（いう感想に）はなるけど
結局自分たちの支払いだと（いう結論に）はなるけど
結局自分たちの支払いだと（いうことに）はなるけど

(As you can see, the interpretation is basically left to the listener - there are multiple possibilities.)
A similar, non-quotation version would have に instead of と (in which case you can't have だ):

結局自分たちの支払いになるけど

That it is quoted will of course be clearer if you add quotation marks, as in 「結局自分たちの支払いだ」とはなるけど. See the example below from NHK.

被害を受けてから『こんな土地とは思わなかった』となる前に、一度自分が住む場所のリスクを確かめてみてほしいと思います

Or other symbols like "!" (from Chiebukuro):

仕事休んだ方がいいです！となるのはどんな時ですか？

These symbols by themselves clearly mark the quoated part in writing, but we don't have an exact equivalent in speech. I think things like だ can have a similar role in speech, in addition to the use of pauses. (I believe English speakers sometimes use "hey" and "oh" in quotatives, at the beginning instead of the end of a quotated part.) Other sentence endings can work similary, as in 支払いですとなる, 支払いじゃないかとなる, etc.
Lastly, this omitted/implicit quotation pattern using となる is colloquial. If found in written form, I'd expect it is a transcribed speech or a social media post that's meant to look colloquial.

The だ and は　(both “is”) serve to emphasize the affirmative against the negative contrast that follows.
It is similar to how we use "does" and "in fact" in English.
Idiomatically:

支払いとなるけど... -> It becomes a payment, but...
支払いとはなるけど... -> It does become a payment, but...
支払いだとはなるけど... -> It does in fact become a payment, but...

The だ seems a bit unusual with なる. It's more commonly used before 言う, where it can be taken as an implicit quote:

駄目だと言ってるが -> 「駄目だ」と言ってるが

